# Outlook newsletter background image and text

Tags: html, html-email, outlook-2010, newsletter

I'm having some difficulties adding text and a background image to a TD in a newsletter, below the code I've used to display them. The background is visible, but the text is not being displayed.

```
       {if !empty($aModules.mkNews)}
            {foreach name=mkNews from=$aModules.mkNews item=mkNews}
                 <td width="230" style="background:url(http://www.example.com/images/content/mkNews/{$mkNews.mkNewsID}/image_{$mkNews.image|getImage:'_big'}) no-repeat center center; text-align: center; font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family:verdana; padding: 20px 0; line-height:22px;">
                     <table background="http://www.example.com/images/content/mkNews/{$mkNews.mkNewsID}/image_{$mkNews.image|getImage:'_big'}" width="230" height="230">
                         <tr>
                             <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family:verdana; padding: 20px 0; line-height:22px;">
                             <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                             <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theImage" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block; height:230px; width:230px; border:0; z-index:1;' src="http://www.example.com/images/content/mkNews/{$mkNews.mkNewsID}/image_{$mkNews.image|getImage:'_big'}"/>
                             <v:shape xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theText" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block; position:absolute; height:230px; width:230px; top:0; left:0; border:0; z-index:2;'>
                             <![endif]-->
                             {$mkNews.message}
                             <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                             </v:shape>
                             <![endif]-->
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                 </td>
             {/foreach}
         {/if}
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction? I don't have much experience with the v-tags that outlook uses.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I figured it out.

The following code works, the text is visible.

```
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theImage" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block; height:230px; width:230px; border:0; z-index:1;' src="http://www.example.com/images/content/mkNews/{$mkNews.mkNewsID}/image_{$mkNews.image|getImage:'_big'}"/>
        <v:shape xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theText" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block; position:absolute; height:230px; width:230px; top:-20px; left:0; border:0; z-index:2;'>
        <![endif]-->
        <table width="230" height="230" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr height="230">
                <td width="230" style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family:verdana; line-height:22px;">{$mkNews.message|convertEncoding:'utf8_decode'|regex_replace:"/[\ï»¿]/":""}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        </v:shape>
        <![endif]-->
```

The text should be in a extra table, then it's visible in outlook 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Background images are not supported in Outlook 2007 and 2010. Check out [Campaign Mointor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for CSS support.

---

Whilst the above is true for CSS, Campaign Monitor mention a solution similar to something your attempting. They use different elements, try

```
<td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" style="background-image: url('http://www.example.com/images/content/mkNews/{$mkNews.mkNewsID}/image_{$mkNews.image|getImage:'_big'}');" background="http://www.example.com/images/content/mkNews/{$mkNews.mkNewsID}/image_{$mkNews.image|getImage:'_big'}" width="230" height="230" valign="top">
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
       <v:rect style="height:230px; width:230px;border:0;" strokecolor="none">
          <v:fill type="tile" color="#DDDDDD" src="http://www.example.com/images/content/mkNews/{$mkNews.mkNewsID}/image_{$mkNews.image|getImage:'_big'}" /></v:fill>
       </v:rect>
       <v:shape id="theText" style="position:absolute;width:230px;height:230px;">
       <![endif]-->
    <p>If you can see this over the image, background images are successful.</p>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
       </v:shape>
    <![endif]-->
</td>
```

I have changed the size and URL to your desired size and src.

They have also added the `xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml` part to the `<html>` tag not the `v` tags.

`<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml>`

I dont have Outlook in which to test it though.

Comment: Background-images do work in Outlook 2010, only the text is not visible.

Comment: Have you looked at [this?](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3363/updated-applying-a-background-image-to-html-email/) - they don't appear to be using `v:image` but similar `v:rect` and `v:fill` elements.